# How to change PHP variable on change with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to change the PHP variable to different values according to each input ?
There is any solution with ajax ?

```
<input type="radio" name="ccc" id="c1" value="1">

<input type="radio" name="ccc" id="c2" value="2">

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myForm input').on('change', function() {
        var value = $('input[name=ccc]:checked', '#myForm').val();

});

    });
</script>

<?php 

$change = "";

echo $change;


 ?>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please read about how `server - php` works with `client - javascript`.

Comment: You can, but you need to send the information by using JQuery, to another php page

Comment: it han't to be another PHP-Page, even the same page would work, but the page has to be reloaded for it and the value has to be passed as a Parameter to the page (for example)

Comment: Whats the purpose behind this?

Comment: How can i do via ajax ?

Answer (score -2):

the PHP-code is parsed BEFORE the code will be submitted to the Client. your javscript will be executed AFTER the code is submitted to the Client, so there isno Chance tochange the PHP-Variable with your Javascript-code *directly*.

i don't know what you are trying to do, but i think AJAX could help you ;)